# How to remove frameon of a subplot and add margins

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I have two subplots like this:

[image]

I generate them with a code like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
fig.suptitle('Vertically stacked subplots')

#plot1
df.plot(kind='barh',x='Attributes',y='Counts', ax=ax1, color='#C0C0C0', 
width=0.3,legend= False)
ax1.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

ax1.tick_params(top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off', 
labelleft='on', labelbottom='on')

#plot2
mypie, _ = ax2.pie(group_size, radius=1.3, labels=group_names, colors= 
[a(0.6), b(0.6), c(0.6), d(0.6)])
plt.setp( mypie, width=0.3, edgecolor='white')
```

I want to remove the frameon of the first plot and I want the first plot smaller and centered and the second one bigger. Also I would like to add the properly margins to each plot so all the text can be read in each of them.

If I apply something like

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.12, bottom=0.11, right=0.7, top=0.78, 
wspace=0.2, hspace=0.2)
```

It affects both subplots and each of them needs a different adjustment
.

Comment: Those are too many questions at once. Concerning the frame, see [spines_demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/spines.html), concerning the position of the plots, you don't tell what exactly you need, but using a gridspec as in [gridspec_multicolumn](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_multicolumn.html) would sure help; or just add the axes whereever you need it via `fig.add_axes`.

Comment: You can use `ax1.axis('off')` to hide the frame on the upper plot

Comment: @Bazingaa : If I do that, then the y labels also dissapear

Comment: @Laura: I see, you are better off then using `ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)` and the same for "right", "top" and "bottom". Check out the links provided by IOBE

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , I have solved using spines.set_visible(False) and gridspec as you suggested.